Docker, testcontainers and network mode
I am not networking expert and have some difficulties to understand what is going on and why.
I have config for testcontainers with mongodb image as follow:
func createMongoContainer(ctx context.Context) (testcontainers.Container, error) {

    req := testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        Image:        "mongo:6",
        ExposedPorts: []string{"27017/tcp"},
        WaitingFor: wait.ForAll(
            wait.ForLog("Waiting for connections"),
            wait.ForListeningPort("27017/tcp"),
        ),
        Name: "mongodb6",
        HostConfigModifier: func(hc *container.HostConfig) {
            hc.NetworkMode = "host"
        },
        Env: map[string]string{},
    }
    genericContainerReq := testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: req,
        Started:          true,
        Reuse:            true,
    }
    container, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(ctx, genericContainerReq)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return container, nil
}

The problem is that on my linux machine I get something like this:
2024/08/22 20:24:10 start container: started hook: all exposed ports, [27017/tcp], were not mapped in 5s: port 27017/tcp is not mapped yet
wait until ready: container exited with code 48

when I remove this part:
HostConfigModifier: func(hc *container.HostConfig) {
            hc.NetworkMode = "host"
        },

it works fine. What exactly above part does? How can I fix this? Meaning have networkmode = host and working container? :)
Docs: :)
https://docs.docker.com/engine/network/
https://golang.testcontainers.org/modules/mongodb/

Sounds like an XY problem to me. Why would you want to use test containers for a job better done with a simple docker command? And if you want to use unit tests, why would you want to put the network into host mode?

You almost never want host networking, which completely disables Docker's networking layer.  If deleting that option addresses your problem, then that's the correct thing to do.
